# android dependency error after cleaning the proejct

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having errors in my game like this :

1- I Import the project.
2- It is showing warnings for gen and src.
3- I clean the project then both error removed automatically.

4- After cleaning New error appears called android dependency (where a file called android apk.jar is automatically getting delete after cleaning)

This is the only one error i have left. why the file is getting delete i dont understand. before cleaning dependency was fine.

please help me what to do with this.
has anyone experienced the same?

Thanks alot

Comment: Right click on project->Android Tools-> Fix Project Properties

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tired this as you said. but no changes found.